# uploadify doesn't work in jquery draggable div

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, uploadify, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to put a uploadify upload video button in a draggable element.

My upload video partial videos/_new_video

```
<p>Upload your Video </p>
<div id="video_attachment"></div>

<%= content_for (:scripts) do%>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    <% session_key = Rails.application.config.session_options[:key] %>
    var uploadify_script_data = {};
    var csrf_token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
    var csrf_param = $('meta[name=csrf-param]').attr('content');

    uploadify_script_data[csrf_param] = encodeURI(encodeURIComponent(csrf_token));
    uploadify_script_data['<%= session_key %>'] = '<%= cookies[session_key] %>';

    $('#video_attachment').uploadify({
      uploader  : '<%= asset_path("uploadify/uploadify.swf") %>',
      script    : '<%= videos_path %>',
      wmode     : 'transparent',
      cancelImg : '<%= asset_path("uploadify/cancel.png") %>',
      fileDataName    : 'attachment',
      scriptData : uploadify_script_data,
      auto      : true,
      buttonText : 'Browse',
      onAllComplete : function(event, data){
        alert("Success!  Please be patient while the video processes.");
      },
      onError: function(event, ID, fileObj, errorObj){
        alert("There was an error with the file you tried uploading.\n Please verify that it is the correct type.")
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require uploadify/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min
//= require uploadify/swfobject
```

profile.js

```
$(document).ready( function(){

/* For edit_draggable */
    $("#edit-draggable").draggable();

$("#edit-draggable").hide();

});
```

in my profile/show, uploadify will work outside the draggable div like this:

```
<%= render "videos/new_video"%> 
<div id="edit-draggable" class="ui-widget-content ui-dialog">

    <%= render "edit"%>
</div>
```

but it won't work inside the draggable div like this:

```
<div id="edit-draggable" class="ui-widget-content ui-dialog">
    <%= render "videos/new_video"%>   
    <%= render "edit"%>
</div>
```

Anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
.draggable({ cursor: "move", cancel: '.uploadify'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've figured this out so I'm going to answer my own question.

Turns out that a draggable div with no drag handle will mask up the click events in the div, so the uploadify button was getting blocked by the draggable.

the solution was to add a drag handle, so the div is only draggable by clicking on part of the div.